# How to link C code that contains WinAPI?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I link C code which contains calls to WinAPI?  While linking I get the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(16): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0'

Consider the following example.

Delphi:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Windows;

{$L C:\Source.obj}

function Test: DWORD; cdecl; external name '_Test';

begin
  WriteLn(Test);
end.
```

C:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD Test(void)
{
   return GetCurrentThreadId();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the Windows header files typically use `__declspec(dllimport)` when they declare functions. For the function in question, its definition in `WinBase.h` is:

```c
WINBASEAPI
DWORD
WINAPI
GetCurrentThreadId(
    VOID
    );
```

When you expand all macros, and re-format that becomes:

```c
__declspec(dllimport) DWORD __stdcall GetCurrentThreadId(void);
```

Now, the use of `__declspec(dllimport)`, and `__stdcall`, tells the linker that the decorated name of the function is `__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0`. You are expected to provide that function in the import library provided with the SDK. You cannot do that in Delphi because it does not accept it. You have a variety of options. The most obvious is to implement the function in the Delphi code. But that is pretty tricky to do because the name is unspeakable. You cannot give a Delphi function that name.

You could shun the Windows header files in your C code and replace them with your own variants that include just what you need in way of types and functions. And define the functions without using `__declspec(dllimport)`. For example:

**C**

```c
typedef unsigned long DWORD; // taken from the Windows header files

DWORD GetCurrentThreadId(void); // this is implemented in the Delphi code to which you link

DWORD MyGetCurrentThreadId(void)
{
   return GetCurrentThreadId();
}
```

**Delphi**

```pascal
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{$LINK MyGetCurrentThreadId.obj}

function _GetCurrentThreadId: DWORD; cdecl;
begin
  Result := Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentThreadId;
end;

function MyGetCurrentThreadId: DWORD; cdecl; external name '_MyGetCurrentThreadId';

begin
  Writeln(MyGetCurrentThreadId);
  Readln;
end.
```

This is not much fun. But I don't see much alternative. The `__stdcall` decoration is going to place `@XX` suffices on your function names, and to the very best of my knowledge you cannot implement such functions in Delphi, because of the unspeakable character `@`.

Obviously in your real code you'd place the type and function declarations into a header file that could be used in place of the Windows header files.

---

You could avoid all of this mess by post-processing the object files. I don't know if a tool exists, but you could process the object file to replace references to `__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0` with references to `GetCurrentThreadId` then life would be simple. The Delphi linker would look for that function name and find it in `Winapi.Windows`.

---

In the comments you have shown how to use [Agner Fog's objconv tool](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) to do exactly this. It runs like this:

**C**

```c
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD MyGetCurrentThreadId(void)
{
   return GetCurrentThreadId();
}
```

**Compilation of C code**

```
cl /c MyGetCurrentThreadId.c
```

**Post-processing of .obj file to undecorate names**

```
objconv -nr:__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0:GetCurrentThreadId MyGetCurrentThreadId.obj MyGetCurrentThreadId_undecorated.obj
```

**Delphi**

```pascal
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{$LINK MyGetCurrentThreadId_undecorated.obj}

const
   _GetCurrentThreadId: function: DWORD; stdcall = Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentThreadId;

function MyGetCurrentThreadId: DWORD; cdecl; external name '_MyGetCurrentThreadId';

begin
  Writeln(MyGetCurrentThreadId);
  Readln;
end.
```

For reasons unknown to me, I cannot persuade the linker to pick up `Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentThreadId` directly. If I undecorate to `GetCurrentThreadId` rather than `_GetCurrentThreadId`, and remove the `const`, then the program compiles and links. But throws an access violation at runtime. Anyway, this trick as suggested by @user15124 provides a manageable workaround.

Comment: What does that mean? Which Delphi feature do you have in mind? Remember that you don't have access to the C++ linker. It is not in play here. I can't see any way round the `@` decoration of `__stdcall` API functions. Do you know how to declare a Delphi function with `@` in its name?

Comment: I think you need to get a better understanding of the C++ linker process. If you include the WIndows header files as is, then they simply define functions. Implementations are provided at link time. Either by actual implementations in one of the obj files, or in a lib file (static or import).  But the decoration of the functions defined in the Windows header files is not something you can influence.  You simply cannot stop that `@` being added.  When linking in Delphi, you have to implement the function. How can you implement a function with an `@` in its name?

Comment: I did manage to demangle it with `objconv.exe` with `objconv -nr:__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0:GetCurrentThreadId source.obj source2.obj`

Comment: It modifies the symbol.

Comment: Can't you be precise? What symbol? This question is all about detail.

Comment: It converts `__imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0` in to `GetCurrentThreadId` which then I can llink. However then the app crashes on call to `Test()`
http://www.agner.org/optimize/

Comment: I've added a postscript to that effect. Exactly what tool you would use that could do this depends very much on the compiler you use, obj format etc. Which I don't know. Anyway, if such a tool does not exist, you could surely write it.

Comment: Oh, it's not `objtool`, it's `objconv`. I guess I wasted my time searching for `objtool` then.

Comment: This is only needed for x32! Works without patching on x64! :)
Although you can still do it.

Comment: Presumably on x64 the decoration does not add the unspeakable `@` and so you can use a function redirect? I'm guessing though. Some more detail in your comments would be nice. That's my advice to you. Take more care over details. Please. I'll write up the objconv trick in my answer.

Comment: I have tested Clang for VS2015 it works great with Delphi.

Comment: Again, I don't know what that refers to. Your precision and attention to detail are lacking here.

Comment: Static linking with Delphi and latest Clang SVN for Visual Studio 2015 works good.

Comment: By the way this syntax is easier. `const
  _GetCurrentThreadId: Pointer  = @Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentThreadId;`